# When i view a posts in wordpress my javascripts and code disappear?

Tags: wordpress

My page: www.acagenturs.dk

On the frontpage below the jquery banner i have 2 divs. 1 for content and 1 for sidebar.

In the sidebar div i display recent news posts on the frontpage.

When i click one of these news items i get redicted to the postpage. This page still uses the fronpage design but for some reason my custom JS file called main.js dissapears which ruins the menu dropdowns and also the sidebar with the news items dissappear.

this code displays the way i display my content on the site:

```
<div id="uscontent">
<div id="uscontentleft">
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>   
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 
</div>
<div id="uscontentright">
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>   
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_field('sidebar'); ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 
</div>
```

i include my script with a standard  tag right before wp_head()

Why does my sidebar dissappear when i click a newspost? and why does the javascript dissapear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if i create a single.php page i can avoid my scripts and code being removed. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add javascript to posts unless you remove the filters first.

Another thing you could try is to call it within the post by its function name. You have to save it as a file first then call it using:

function FILENAME(){ desired process}

Comment: could you elaborate on filters?